# Looking for meta-recipe for installing homebrew recipes under BSD

Tags: freebsd, bsd, netbsd

Is there a way to install homebrew recipes under BSD?  (NetBSD, to be more precise.)

(To make matters worse, I don't have write access to `/usr/local` in this system, so I'd be installing `homebrew` itself under `$HOME/homebrew` or somesuch.  The `homebrew` documentation discourages, but does not entirely rule out, installing `homebrew` anywhere else other than under `/usr/local`.  In this case I'd have no choice on the matter.)

Comment: Do these package come with a `./configure` and a `--prefix=/some/path/which/defaults/to/usr/local/when/not/manually/set/` ?